# Growing text input view - swift examples

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying un the past two days to implement a UITextView that grows as the user types. Like whats-app does.

I've found examples here with textViewDidChange but that didn't really work as it needs to not only grow but also move upwards. And as the textview sits inside a view that also holds the send button, they both have to grow upwards.

Also found some other frameworks.

https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController - looks really cool and may do everything I need but I found no examples of it running swift. The sample project provided I could not run.

https://github.com/MatejBalantic/MBAutoGrowingTextView - could not really get it to work upwards.

I am looking for some help on how to implement that using SWIFT or maybe a sample project of the SLACK one running on swift that is not the sample project on github. Or maybe a bit of code showing how to link the UITextView to the Slack class and make it work inside a viewController class.

Comment: Do you use auto layout? Is there a maximum height for the UITextView? What's the expected behavior once the maximum height is reached?

Comment: so technically what you want is to as the person writes you want the textfview to get bigger and the container view to get bigger base on the text content right?

Comment: **Lamour**, exactly that. I found specially tricky to make them both grow upwards and move up and down as the keyboard gets activated or not.

**Joe**, yes I use auto-layout. Once the maximum height is reached I would like to stop the UITextView from growing and then bring the scroll.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'm currently using for my inputAccessoryView.

I have a toolbar that holds the UITextView and send button and listens to textViewDidChange events like so:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let oldHeight = textView.height
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 100.0 //beyond this value the textView will scroll
    var newHeight = min(textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height, maxHeight)
    newHeight = ceil(newHeight)
    if newHeight != oldHeight {
        textView.frame.size.height = max(newHeight, barHeight)
        updateHeight(height: newHeight)
    }
}
```

The goal here is to set the new textView height. Then I update the toolbar height as well

```
public func updateToolBarHeight(height: CGFloat) {
    for constraint in constraints {
        if constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height && constraint.firstItem as! NSObject == self {
            constraint.constant = max(barHeight, height)
        }
    }
    setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    sendButton.origin.y = max(0, height - barHeight)
}
```

barHeight is my default toolbar height (set to 50.0).
and I also update my sendButton position to stay at the bottom of the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `UITextView`, you can simply make it fit to its content by setting:

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

This will make it grow with the input.

Answer (score -4):

All you need to do for a UITextView to grow automatically is to set numberOfLines to 0.  Then it will grow infinitely.  I hope that works for you!